# Exclude default value fields returned by mongoengine only()

Tags: mongodb, mongoengine

Suppose I have a class User which has 10 fields, all with default values assigned to them.

If i did something like this:

```js
docs = User.objects.only('field1', 'field2', 'field3')
print docs[0]._fields.keys()
```

This would still print all 10 fields as keys (7 of them would just have default values or None).

Is there a way to force the QuerySet returned using only() to actually exclude the fields that were not downloaded?
The docs doesn't to specify any ways to do this.

MongoEngine documentation:
http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/querying.html#retrieving-a-subset-of-fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This currently isn't possible (as of MongoEngine 0.8.6) but has been marked down for the 0.9 release

Comment: Thanks for the heads up.  So what is the primary usage case of only()? Is it for faster read performance from mongo (and smaller memory footprint)?  Are there any builtin properties of the fields that I can use to identify whether a field is getting retrieved with the default value (as opposed to an actual value)

Comment: Noting here that today we do have it: `.exclude()`